# How to set arbitrary padding value to Keras conv2d filter?

Tags: keras, convolution

I am trying to implement inception module myself using Keras but i find both 'valid' and 'same' padding cannot meet my need. for instance, i would like to get 9×9 feature map from applying a 5×5 filter to 11×11 input, could anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using `ZeroPadding2D()` layer? Suppose your stride is 1, set the padding parameter `(3, 3)`, then use `same` for conv2d. [Here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) is the description.

Comment: Thanks, ZeroPadding2D works but this API design is confusing to me.